# Printing gradient over metallic silver

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

[image]I have a logo design that contains gradient which I want to be printed on a metallic silver paper. Should I add a white plate with white gradient behind the logo but I am afraid white area will show through the gradient. Will it be fine if I just use the logo with gradient without white plate? But according to my knowledge every colored area except black should have a white plate behind it when printing over metallic silver. So I have two concerns, If I don't use white plate behind logo it might not get printed properly or If I use white gradient plate behind it might show white area instead of metallic silver paper. If you say I can use my logo that contains gradient without white plate and it will be printed fine over metallic silver, my problem will be solved.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both approaches are valid, depends what appearance you want. Can you share an image of the logo?

Comment: In my opinion, a little test can solve your doubts.

Comment: @ Westside, I have attached the logo, please check.

Comment: @LeoNas, I did the printing proof but white area appeared where gradient fades out instead of the transparency that I wanted. Is it because I have used a white plate behind it containing white to transparent gradient. Now I am wondering what if I don't use a white plate behind the logo, will that color gradient of my logo be printed over metallic silver?

Comment: @sameer you need to talk to your printer, The order of each plate is something that they define. Personally i would make a gradient on the metallic and put that on top

Comment: You need to speak to the printer. You'll just end up chasing ghosts without *direct* input from the print provider. You aren't printing these yourself are you? If so.. what are you printing to? and you have white ink? I assume *every* image you've posted is a *mock up* not actual results.

Comment: @joojaa, thanks a lot for the feedback. I will talk to the printer about it.

Comment: @Scott, you are right I have to talk to the printer about it. I have posted mockup to show the complete problem. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2):

The white color is showing because, in offset lithography, the white color is opaque, and the red (or M+Y) is much more transparent.
There are a few options you can make in this cases:

- don't use the white plate behind red (only for the lettering). In that
  case, you will get a darker, rich color with a metallic effect, and it looks great, but it depends on the look and feel you wish to accomplish. If you need a strong red, avoid this option.
- if using a white background, the gradient shouldn't be the same as the red gradient, because you'll encounter the issue you already have. The gradient should start somewhere around the position of the letter "P" in your logo and end around "T". Basically, it should be shorter, and than you won't see the white behind the red gradient.
- the third option is to start the white
  gradient with 50-70% white, and finish in 0%, so that you don't have
  a solid white at all in that area. What you`ll accomplish with this
  approach is to get a nice red, but it will get some depth to it,
  because a small amount of metallic paper will shine through and
  interact with the transparent red. This way you get the best of both
  worlds - using the advantages of a more expensive metalized paper and
  the opaqueness of white. You may need to make a test with reducing or
  enhancing the pressure of white plate during the print process to get
  the right result.